# SQL Bulk Copy - Data Type Conversion Error - How to get the Error Row / Item / String?

Tags: c#, sql, debugging, sqlbulkcopy

I'm trying to bulk copy a datatable into DB and i get an `InvalidOperationException` saying

> The given value of type String from the data source cannot be
>   converted to type float of the specified target column.

That's fine.

Looking at the inner(most) exception, it's a `FormatException` throws at `Double.ParseDouble` in mscorlib saying

> Input string was not in a correct format

Okay.

So 2 questions:

- Is there any way of hooking into bulk copy and getting the exact input string / error row? Even the notify after kludge only works for DB copy and not at this convert step.
- Why the HELL did the writers of this lib(bulk copy, not parse double) choose to throw the damn exception without adding in which specific string / id / some reference to what caused this error? Sheer laziness? or there is an actual reason (security or otherwise) why offending inputs/strings cannot be included in exception messages? Is there any good reason for obfuscating the cause of such an error?

There are a bunch of questions on SQLBulkCopy on SO itself and this kind of issue is the most common. In all the answers people just investigate the data piece by piece elsewhere. Nowhere do i see a hint of debugging support.....